# How to correct work with timezone of Australia

Tags: php, datetime, timezone

I store dates in UTC format in database, also user has hour offset

Here is my code

```
$this->timezoneName = timezone_name_from_abbr("", 10 * 3600, 0);
$d = new \DateTime($date);
$d->setTimezone(new \DateTimeZone($this->timezoneName));
return $d->format("d.m.Y H:i");
```

All works correct, for any $offset from 0 to +9, but for +10 (Australia) it returns date with offset +11 not +10
How to fix it?

Update- here is more correct code

```
$this->timezoneName = timezone_name_from_abbr("", $offset * 3600, 0);
$d = new \DateTime('8.11.2016 10:00:00', new \DateTimeZone('UTC'));
    $d->setTimezone(new \DateTimeZone($this->timezoneName));
return $d->format("d.m.Y H:i");
```

I get 08.11.2016 21:00

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Australia is currently GMT+11 (at least in Caberra).

Comment: Of course, there is not just one time zone for Australia. In Adelaide the time zone is GMT+10.5 and in Perth the time zone is GMT+8. This question is too broad.

Comment: Works fine. https://3v4l.org/ZRXhR

Comment: check this https://3v4l.org/6TFdF

Comment: Fixed offsets are no good, as parts of Australia uses daylight saving time.  You have 5 different time zones on the mainland alone.  There are 13 different TZ identifiers... Australia is a big place.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_in_Australia

Comment: I know about  daylight saving time, but I need to use offset without DST. How can it be done with DateTime?

Answer (score 1):

Calling `timezone_name_from_abbr("", 10 * 3600, 0)` returns `Australia/Melbourne`.

Melbourne started daylight saving time (aka "summer time") [on October 2, 2016](http://www.timeanddate.com/time/change/australia/melbourne?year=2016).  It will be in effect [until April 2, 2017](http://www.timeanddate.com/time/change/australia/melbourne?year=2017).

On standard time, Melbourne is UTC+10.  During daylight saving time, Melbourne is UTC+11.  This explains your results.

In general, don't use fixed offsets because they cannot account for DST and other historical differences.  Used named identifiers instead.

Comment: Thanks, but I need time without DST, so for this reason I use fixed offset. How can it be achieved with DateTime?

Comment: Well, if you must, you can use zones like `Etc/GMT-10` which will work for whole-hour zones and are primarily for ships at sea.  It's not such a great idea to try to ignore DST in the first place.  DST is part of the reality of how clocks are actually set.  If you use those zones, keep in mind that the offset in the zone name will have its sign inverted.